# How can I retrieve data from an array, 3 at a time?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Is there a better way in PHP to access this array in groups of three?

Let's say my array is a comma separated string like:

```
("Thora","Birch","Herself","Franklin Delano","Roosevelt","Himself (archive footage)","Martin Luther","King","Himself (archive footage) (uncredited)")
```

Although the array can end up being much larger, each one will be different but still in logical groups of three (firstname, lastname, role).

What I'm trying to accomplish is looping through the array in groups of three, so that the first record would have `firstname[0]=>"Thora", lastname[0]=>"Birch" and role[0]=>"Herself".`

I'm only used to `foreach` loops but don't see an extra parameter like "for each 3" so maybe someone can shed some light?

Comment: You have to use for() to step by 3, I don't know any function to directly do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a function called [array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk) designed for this task.

Try this:

```
$sets = array_chunk($people, 3);
foreach ($sets as $set) {
  //you could use the following line to put each field into a nice variable
  list ($firstname, $lastName, $role) = $set;

  //if all you want to do is collect the values, do this 
  $firstNames[] = $set[0];
  $lastNames[] = $set[1];
  $role[] = $set[2];
}
```

Note that the last chunk might not be of size 3, so you should check that keys 1 and 2 are set with isset, if you can't guarantee that your array is always a multiple of 3 in length.

Comment: make sure to call array_chunk with the chunk size: array_chunk($people, 3)

Comment: This is one I haven't heard of, thanks for the help! I'm going to give this a run through tomorrow, looks nice and elegant!

Comment: It's worth having a look through the PHP manual at different array functions, especially when you're about to reinvent the wheel in your own code! Chances are there's a built in function.

Comment: Thanks David, this one worked like a charm for what I was doing, and the list function helped out even further.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for`-loop for this, assuming your 'people' array has a length of `3n`.

```
$people = array("Thora","Birch","Herself","Franklin Delano","Roosevelt","Himself (archive footage)","Martin Luther","King","Himself (archive footage) (uncredited)");
$firstName = array();
$lastName = array();
$role = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($people); $i += 3){
   $firstName[] = $people[$i];
   $lastName[] = $people[$i+1];
   $role[] = $people[$i+2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about 
Pseudo code

```
for Index = 0 index = length index +=3
{
   Firstname= array[index]
   middlename = array[index+1]
   lastname = array[index+2]
   Do Something with them...
}
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer, but I can't imagine this not doing EXACTLY what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you use PHP >= 5.3:

```
array_walk(
        range(1,9),//<== normally your array, range(1,9) is just an example/test value
        function($value,$key) use (&$return){
                 $return[$key % 3][] = $value;
        });
var_dump($return);
```